# I want to render my page after downloading the csv files to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> After downloading the CSV file it is showing the empty(white Index)
>   page i need to be refresh the page each time,To get the index page,can
>   any one tell me how to render the page after downloading the csv each
>   time.

```
class EmployeeExportsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @employees = Employee.all.order('id ASC')
        @entities = Entity.get_active_entities
        @employees = Employee.includes(:entity).all
        employee_ids = @employees.map(&:id)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.csv { send_data @employees.to_csv }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: try `format.csv { send_data @employees.to_csv, disposition: :attachment}`

Comment: Actually, try `:type => 'text/csv', :disposition => 'attachment'`

Comment: My Functionalities are working perfectly but only the problem is page is freezing after im giving for downloading, which is coming full white page, thn i need to be refresh the page to get my index page back..... please give me the solution for avoiding the freezing,  or when im clicking for downloading let my index page get refresh by default

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the url, add a `.csv` extension.